# How to extract special targets from an image using opencv - python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to image processing. Please give me some advice on extracting the red box area in the following image。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrENs.jpg)
I have done some simple image processing, including image reading, graying, binarization, candy edge detection, morphological processing. 
I hope this helps.
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeAfy.jpg)
[graying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R3Et.jpg)
[binarization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNfDU.png)
[candy edge detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O53Cm.png)
[morphological processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU0p3.png)
This is the code.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    in_file = r"D:test_cut_2.jpg"
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(in_file, dtype=np.uint8), -1)
    # graying
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # candy edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)
    # binarization
    _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(gray, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    # morphological processing
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
    dilated = cv2.dilate(binary_image, kernel, iterations=2)
    dst = cv2.erode(binary_image, kernel, iterations=2)
    cv2.imshow('Original Photo', image)
    cv2.imshow('gray photo', gray)
    cv2.imshow('Binary Image', binary_image)
    cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
    cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
    cv2.imshow('dilated', dilated)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I do not see a green box.  What I see is red!

Comment: sorry. This is a mistake in the writing process. 
I have modified it. 
If it is convenient for you, please write me some suggestions.

Comment: I think we need a little more context. The objective is to detect the text/characters present on this particular image? Will the text/characters change ? Will the conditions of the image change, like the water level?

If the conditions stay the same, you could hardcode a ROI to always extract the same area of interest, but if you need a more dynamic solution, the context will help :D